# javascript setter why does it seem to be called 3 times at execution whereas it called only once from constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have log set text and it is triggered 3 times why ?
see behavior here https://jsfiddle.net/5kv2g6hc/

```
class Test {

  set text(text) {
    console.log(text); // 3 times ?!!!
    this.text = text;
  }
  
  constructor() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
      .then((response) => {
        response.text().then((response) => {
          this.text = response;
          // console.log(this.text);
        });
      });
  }
}

let test = new Test();
```

Comment: `this.text = anything` is a call to the setter, even inside the setter.

Comment: You need to use a different property to hold the actual value, not the same property as the setter.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting infinite recursion.

Comment: Please don't include code that needlessly relies on API requests that we can't make in debugging. This is by definition not a [MCVE]. If your behavior needs an asynchronous callback to be provoked, you can get this with a simple `setTimeout`.

Comment: @user229044 of course you can it's a public API since it works here https://jsfiddle.net/5kv2g6hc/

Comment: @user310291 I'm not willing to unnecessarily connect to an API to debug something that has nothing to do with the network, and your question shouldn't require me to do so. I have no idea what that API does, and I don't want to know. Reducing your code to a [MCVE] means removing anything not specifically required to reproduce your problem. Layering network requests onto a problem involving JavaScript getters/setters is completely unnecessary and simply obscures the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's called more than 3 times. It's a recursive call.

It is first initialized in the promise handler by using `this.text = response`.
Then, within the setter you call `this.text = text` which basically triggers the same setter once again. And so it goes indefinitely (limited by V8 stack and stack overflow error is thrown).

When setters are used new props are created to store the value, because name of a getter/setter cannot be the same as the one storing the value.

So your code should be modified. There are two ways. The old one by using an underscore to tell that it's a private prop and shouldn't be used directly from the outside

```
class Test {
  set text(text) {
    console.log(text);
    this._text = text; // <- here _text instead of text
  }
  
  constructor() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
      .then((response) => {
        response.text().then((response) => {
          this.text = response;
          // console.log(this.text);
        });
      });
  }
}

let test = new Test();
```

And a new one which uses the new syntax of real private properties introduced in JS recently

```
class Test {
  #text; // <- first, declare the private prop

  set text(text) {
    console.log(text);
    this.#text = text; // <- then use #text instead of text
  }
  
  constructor() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
      .then((response) => {
        response.text().then((response) => {
          this.text = response;
          // console.log(this.text);
        });
      });
  }
}

let test = new Test();
```

Comment: "this.text = text which basically triggers the same setter once again." ?! I don't understand arg text argument is not class property. As for infinite call that's not what I observe 3 times is far from infinite see here https://jsfiddle.net/5kv2g6hc/ ;)

Comment: ok my mistake it is infinite https://jsfiddle.net/5kv2g6hc/1/

Comment: does # a special symbol for private or just a convention I never see in js doc ?

Comment: @user310291 it's part of the syntax.

Comment: @Pointy why it isn't enough to just rename text to arg ? It does work here https://jsfiddle.net/5kv2g6hc/1/ but I don't understand how it differs from #text

Comment: You're renaming the *argument to the function*, not the property on the class instance. The problem with `this.text = anything` is with `this.text`, not `anything`.